# %dd, %ff .... invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, utf-8

In my rails app, when I add `%dd` or `%ff` in url parameter, why it returns `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`?

I have a regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$` to catch if string includes letters + numbers + underscores only. Then when I add `%dd`, or `%ff` in my url parameter, it returns `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` error.

What does `%dd` and `%ff` means?

UPDATE:

My controller:

```
def search
  regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$'
  @search = params[:search]
  unless @search.match(alpha_num_under_regex).nil?
   @users = User.find_by_name(@search)
   render 'api/v1/users/show', status: 200, formats: :json
else
  @users = []
  render 'api/v1/users/show', status: 422, formats: :json
end
```

My URL:

```
localhost:3000/api/v1/users/show?search=%dd
```

When params `search=%d` it return `Bad Request` which is ok. But when I added another `d`, `search=%dd` or `search=a%dd`, it returns `Action Controller: Exception caught` - `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`.

The question is, how can I pass `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` error?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding :: in other words, one needs to escape `%ff` when using it in URL.

Comment: How could I catch or rescue these `Percent encoding` in rails?

Comment: The question is not “how to escape it in rails,” the question is “how to pass it to rails.” You might want to read and understand what is written in the link I provided. Also, please share the exact URL you are trying to access and your controller code, handling this case.

Comment: I updated my question above

Answer (score 1):

From [`Wiki`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding):

> **Percent-encoding**, also known as **URL encoding**, is a mechanism for encoding information in a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) under certain circumstances. Although it is known as URL encoding it is, in fact, used more generally within the main Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) set, which includes both Uniform Resource Locator (URL) and Uniform Resource Name (URN). As such, it is also used in the preparation of data of the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` media type, as is often used in the submission of HTML form data in HTTP requests.

The query `search=%dd` is according to above treated/interpreted as `search=<BYTE_WITH_ORD_VALUE_0xDD>`. Ruby expects this string to be UTF-8, but `0xDD` is not a valid UTF-8 symbol.

To avoid this problem and pass what was intended, one should URL-escape the search query explicitly by substituting `%` ⇒ `%25` (the latter is apparently the percent-encoded percent sign itself.)

```
localhost:3000/api/v1/users/show?search=%25dd
```

the above will send `%dd` query to rails.

**NB** to be safe, one should build url queries according to the common rule, specified in the article linked above:

> [List of reserved characters]
>
> **Other characters in a URI must be percent encoded.**